# How Do I Reset One MSSQL Table Row's Columns Except ID Column

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, identity

I am looking for a query to use in PHP that looks something like this:

`$sql = "TRUNCATE * Columns EXCEPT ID WHERE ID = '$idvar'";`

I realize that this is probably not usable syntax, but if someone knows a query that works like the one I posted above, that would be perfect.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to blank out only specific columns on an entire table except where a specific id? I'm really looking for clarification because I can't tell what you are trying to do with that query. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: I doubt there's a query that automatically clears all columns, or all columns except one. You have to use `UPDATE` and then `SET` all the columns you want to reset.

Comment: You could do it by deleting the row and then inserting it with just the `ID` column, all the other columns will get default values.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the best way to reset an MSSQL table row's columns except it's ID, is to use the `UPDATE` statement, and then `SET` all of the columns except the `ID` column to `NULL`, or a `space` character.

Here is the query I am going to use:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET col1=' ', col2=' ', col3=' ' WHERE id = '$idvar'";
```